# List items not aligned with custom formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I am experimenting with json view formatting. I am working with [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/contenttype-format) template, that should show the list items next to each other like on the screenshot:
[image: sample]

Instead, they are presented like this in my list:

[image: strange layout]

Can somebody please tell me what to change in the formatting to really align the items in lines?

Edit: looks like, the page looks good for my colleagues, only on my pc not. Any ideas?

Comment: Might be some old leftovers cached in your browser after your development. Try a hard refresh (ctrl + F5) to see if the solves the problem.

Comment: No didn't help, I even tried another browser (IE) where that site was never opened. I even restarted my pc. Might be my screen resolution (4k screen)?